# Close pop up and refresh parent page javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout, salesforce

i want to close pop up and refresh parent but after few seconds delay to make sure all data is received. currently i have the following

```
function closeAndRefresh(){    
  setTimeout(function()
 {     
window.open('/{!currSubId}','_top');
window.location = window.location.href;
return true;
},5000)}
```

This code refreshes the parent but inside the popup, so the pop up does not close, rather the parent shows refreshed - in pop up

Comment: Why is the pop up inside a timeout?

Comment: well the idea is that closing and refreshing is inside of the timeout.

Comment: so you put the close code inside and the pop up outside.

Answer (score 0):

So move the pop up outside of the timeout, give it a name, call close, and reload.

```
function closeAndRefresh(){    
    var winPop = window.open('/{!currSubId}','_top');  //load pop up give it a name
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        winPop.close();  //close pop up
        window.location.reload(true);  //refresh current page
    },5000);
}
```

You could just use an Ajax call to the server and not have to deal with a pop up and wondering if the pop up blocker will block it or not knowing if the call completetd. When the call comes back from the call, you can just reload the page.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer, however, this closes the pop up but does not refresh after 5 seconds (or doesn't wait 5 seconds to refresh)

Comment: If the pop up closes it should reload the current page. Any errors in the console?

Comment: But i want it to reload after few seconds, so i am sure it collected all the data (takes like 3 seconds). no console errors

Comment: I am not sure why the code is not working, it should reload the page that the code is run on.

Comment: Cause it is running on the pop up page - i am afraid. I am sorry if i wasn't clear on that.

Comment: What is running on the pop up page? You are opening a pop up in a pop up?

Comment: function closeAndRefresh() is called from a button of the pop up, and the window.open('/{!currSubId}','_top'); was suppose to open the parent and reaload but i want that action to be postponed for few seconds

Comment: Why are you opening the parent? Why are you not setting the url directly on the parent? `window.opner.location.href = "asaddasd"; window.close();`